# JQuery image swap inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve something similar to [this](http://www.georgetowncupcake.com/menu.html).

The image will be coming from a feed url,  I'm unsure of how to prevent each of them opening up in a new window, here is what I have so far:

**Javascript:**

jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#more-views a').click(function(){
            $('#main-image img').fadeOut('slow').delay(2000).remove();
            //$('#main-image').append('&lt;img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" alt="" style="display:none;" /&gt;');

            $('#main-image').append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('data') + '" alt="" style="display:none;" />');
            $('#main-image img').fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="more-views">
    <a data="http://www.domain.com/image1.jpg"> 1 Day</a>
    <a data="http://www.domain.com/image2.jpg"> 5 Days</a>
    <a data="http://www.domain.com/image3.jpg"> 1 Month</a>
</div>


<div id="main-image">
    <img src="http://www.domain.com/image1.jpg" alt="1d" />
</div>
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Mind if I ask why such an old version of jQuery..is this a requirement or do you have free reign over which version to choose?

Comment: Hi there, actually I could use: v2.0.0

Comment: What is `HTML 1 Day 5 Days <div id="default-market-chart">...</div>`? Are those links broken?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't display correctly, but here is my HTML:

    <div id="more-views">
        <a href="http://www.something.com/image1.jpg"> 1 Day</a>

         <a href="http://www.something.com/image2.jpg"> 5 Days</a>
        
         <a href="http://www.something.com/image3.jpg"> 1 Month</a>
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a line to your JavaScript to test and see if it will add the paragraph tag. If it does, you may instead have a problem with the the urls for your images instead of with the code here.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#more-views a').click(function(){
        $('#main-image p').fadeOut('slow').delay(2000).remove();
//-------v add this line for testing
        $('#main-image').append('<p>' + $(this).attr('href') + '</p>);

        $('#main-image').append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" alt="" style="display:none;" />');
        $('#main-image p').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

==Less Old==

Ok, I think I understand your problem now.  Instead of having your `<a>` tags have a `href` attribute, use a `data` attribute instead.

So your anchor tag should look like this:

```
<a data='domain.com/image1.jpg'>image1</a>
```

And then you will need to replace two of your JavaScript lines:

```
$('#main-image').append('&lt;img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" alt="" style="display:none;" /&gt;');
```

Becomes:

```
$('#default-market-chart').append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('data') + '" alt="" style="display:none;" />');
```

And, you will have to replace all instances of `#main-image` in your JavaScript with `#default-market-chart`, since you don't seem to have an element with and id of `main-image`

==Old==

Try replacing the `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<` and `>`, so that your web page will treat the string you are giving it as an HTML tag, and not just a string.

Comment: Well the problems I'm having with my code is that each image opens up in a new window, essentially I just want them to to be swappable on the same page, very similar to the cupcake menu site...

Comment: Hi Susan,
So I replaced those two lines, but now the links are inactive...am I missing something?

Really appreciate your help btw!

Comment: Made the edits above, and updated my code at the top of the page.  The three links are no longer active now..

Comment: They should no longer look active, but they should still function. You can change the css, or, you can change the 'data' attribute back to 'href' since that seems to not have been the cause of your problem, but remember to do it in the JavaScript as well.

Comment: Thanks.
Images still opening in a new window :-(

Comment: I have it working in a js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AFtKu/11/) with `<p>` tags instead of images.

Comment: does that jsfiddle help out at all?

Comment: Hey Sarah - yes definately works in fiddle, but can't seem to get it working with my image url, something like: http://www.usatoday.idmanagedsolutions.com/charts/web/quote.chart?SYMBOL_US=GCI&WIDTH=300&HEIGHT=120&RESOLUTION=15M&TIME_SPAN=1D&PAGE=ETF&DECIMAL=2&DATE_PREFIX=As%20of%20